# Cbind dataframes in an alternating order

Tags: r

Let's say I have two data frames with the following columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame("A.One"=1:10, "A.Two"=1:10, "A.Three"=1:10)
df2 <- data.frame("B.One"=1:10, "B.Two"=1:10, "B.Three"=1:10)
```

I want to cbind them in a particular order (or cbind them normally and reorder them to achieve that order):

```
x <- magic_cbind(df1, df2)
colnames(x)
```

Desired output:

```
A.One B.One A.Two B.Two A.Three B.Three
```

That is, I wish to have them sorted by the suffix - first we have all Ones, then all Twos, according to the order they were in originally in each data frame. I hope this explanation makes sense...

This seems very simple but I can't figure it out and I don't really know what to search for, how to call this ordering...

Comment: `ggplot` has an unexported function that can help: `as.data.frame(ggplot2:::interleave(df1, df2))`

Answer (score 6):

We could use `base R` to do this.  After `cbind`ing the datasets, just `order` the columns based on the concantenated sequence of each dataset

```
cbind(df1, df2)[order(c(seq_along(df1), seq_along(df2)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` answer.  Bind rows, use `select` to determine order of columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame("A.One"=1:10, "A.Two"=1:10, "A.Three"=1:10)
df2 <- data.frame("B.One"=1:10, "B.Two"=1:10, "B.Three"=1:10)

df3 <- cbind(df1, df2) %>%
  select(A.One, B.One, A.Two, B.Two, A.Three, B.Three)
```

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a solution that can be scaled for arbitrary column number